# Split poylines with a grid in AutoCAD

Tags: split, autocad, polyline

I have a layer in AutoCAD which consists of many rectangle polygons (created with polylines) with the same size that touch each other. So it's like a grid.  And I also have another layer on the bottom of it which consists of many polylines - city boundaries, forest and agricultural areas. Now I want to "cut" the second one according to the grid so that all polylines will be split in the size of each rectangle of the grid.

Is it possible in AutoCAD? I think this can be done with ArcGIS but how can I do it AutoCAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to find all intersection points and redraw the polyline segments for each grid, then delete the original polylines.

The article at the following link might help: http://www.acadnetwork.com/index.php?topic=181.0

Comment: Thank you ..!!  Is this done with AutoLisp or is this a programming language ?

Comment: The example linked above is C#.Net.  You're going to need a managed language (VB.Net, C#.Net, etc) or ObjectARX to do what you want.  AutoLisp might be able to do it also.